# How to Fix a Dynamic Document Size Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Menu-list, and when I pass the mouse hover an item display another list,
but this list is larger and change the height of the document.
This create a bug in the page.

[image.gif here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWiFJ.gif)

I try with this. When the documents height changes go to top with the scroll but it does not work

```js
var tamHtml;

$(window).load(function () {
    tamHtml = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
});


$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() { 
    if($(this).height() != tamHtml) {
        topFunction();
    }
});

function topFunction() {
    if (tamHtml != document.documentElement.scrollHeight) {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        tamHtml = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can override its `css` in `jquery` for this.

Comment: I added padding-bottom in the container. Tnx man.